# the Paypal smart Button Doesn't render correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using the button with Vuejs but I only need the paypal yellow button, I tried to hide the credit card button with all the ways in the docs and even in here on the stack but it either renders both buttons or half the first button [half button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLjlf.png),[Both buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubTlh.png)

Here's my script

```
loadPaypalScript() {
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src =
    "https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=Aeg-skCx0jYCCZ2qE62Wsu_bxR3agmnYX41BuSGRhGwAP_YYEo7rKNL2P49UIHCxJj_tSuoylwkaV4gn&currency=EUR&commit=false&components=buttons,funding-eligibility";
  script.addEventListener("load", () => this.loaded = false);
  document.body.appendChild(script);
},

window.paypal
    .Buttons({
      fundingSource: paypal.FUNDING.PAYPAL,
      locale : this.$i18n.locale == 'de' ? 'de_DE' : 'en_US',
      style: {
        color: 'blue',
        label: 'checkout',
        shape: 'pill',
        fundingicons: false,    /* true | false */
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by your site's CSS, the container is not tall enough.

Make sure there are no negative margins or overflow, etc.

Comment: https://img.onl/BPef9s I cant see anything in my css, im using bootstrap 4.6. the wierd thing about all this is if I let both of the buttons render they work just fine.

Comment: You may not be able to see it, but that is the issue. You screenshot shows nothing of value.

Comment: I double checked my css, still couldn't find anything. Then I added `layout: horizontal` to the style it worked. I dont think its the right answer but it will do for now. anyways thank you very much for the help

Comment: The default vertical view and layout horizontal both have taglines. Your site's CSS is covering up the bottom portion of what is rendered. When there is a single button with no tagline, only "half" of it show.  As for the right answer, we cannot help you find the issue with your page's DOM without seeing it.